# Kivy- Python - check if textField is not empty

Tags: python, button, kivy, textfield

I need to do some actions in `on_release` part of button but only if text in the TextField is not empty.

Also a connected question is how to insert only numbers? I tried using `input_filter` (so if it works I don't need to check the emptiness) but all i got was crushing of an app if there was not INT. One more thing that I want to do this without creating a special class to check all the properties, i want to do it either in the body of `MDTextField` or using the button.

I have text field:

```
MDTextField:
    id: times_amount
    hint_text: "Times a day"
    mode: "rectangle"
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
    helper_text: "Insert only numbers"
```

And a button:

```
MDFloatingActionButton:
    id: ok_but
    pos_hint:{"center_x": .8, "center_y": .2}
    icon: 'check'
    on_release:     #should I use this?-> if times_amount.text!=''
        app.add_object(my_object)
        times_amount.text=''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some logic in your `kv`, like:

```
MDFloatingActionButton:
    id: ok_but
    pos_hint:{"center_x": .8, "center_y": .2}
    icon: 'check'
    on_release:     #should I use this?-> if times_amount.text!=''
        app.add_object(my_object) if times_amount.text != '' else None
        times_amount.text=''
```

Comment: Thanks! that was the decision

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, the full code looks like this:

```
MDTextField:
    id: times_amount
    hint_text: "Times a day"
    mode: "rectangle"
    required: True
    input_filter:'int'
    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
    helper_text: "Insert only numbers"
```

and

```
FloatLayout:
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        id: ok_but
        pos_hint:{"center_x": .8, "center_y": .2}
        icon: 'check'
        on_release:
            app.add_object(my_object) if times_amount.text!='' else None
            times_amount.text=''
```